# rollback and commit only when not in auto-commit mode

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbutils

The [javadoc for Connection#rollback](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback) clearly states:

> This method should be used only when auto-commit mode has been disabled.

A similar caveat exists for the `commit` method.

However, looking at the code, e.g. in [Apache commons DbUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbutils/commons-dbutils/1.6/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.java#DbUtils.rollback%28java.sql.Connection%29) I see only:

```
public static void rollback(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.rollback();
        }
}
```

It seems weird to have a utility function only to guard against NPE and to omit to test the auto-commit mode. I would have expected something along the following lines:

```
public static void rollback(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    if (conn != null) {
        final boolean autoCommit = (boolean) conn.getAutoCommit();
        if (!autoCommit)
            DbUtils.rollback(conn);
    }
}
```

Is the caveat in the javadoc (that `rollback` should only be called when auto-commit mode has been disabled) actually observed in practice and, if so, why would a successful JDBC library not bother with it?

Comment: The reasoning is, that if you haven't disabled autoCommit, why are you bothering calling `DbUtils.rollback(..)` or `DbUtils.commit(..)` in your code, and if you call them that is clearly a bug that you should notice. To be honest given modern try-with-resources, I find a lot of the `DbUtils` methods pretty useless.

Answer (score -1):

When auto-comit is enabled the rollback method simply hasno effect.